# FileNotFoundException in loading spring.ftl using Freemarker in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I'm stuck in the integration of Freemarker in my Spring application.
I have a lib responsible of the generation of html to pdf it which is inject in my webapp.
The spring.ftl is in a templates folder inside resources of my lib module

my-lib/src/main/resources/templates/spring.ftl

I defined a FileTemplateLoader which refer to templates folder and added an auto_import properties for spring.ftl

When I try to generate the pdf file I got a FileNotFoundException when the Freemarker config try to set the template loader

Configuration methode :

```
private static Configuration getConfig() throws IOException, TemplateException {
        // Create your Configuration instance, and specify if up to what FreeMarker
        // version (here 2.3.32) do you want to apply the fixes that are not 100%
        // backward-compatible. See the Configuration JavaDoc for details.
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_32);

        // Specify the source where the template files come from. Here I set a
        // plain directory for it, but non-file-system sources are possible too:
        //cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("/where/you/store/templates"));

        // From here we will set the settings recommended for new projects. These
        // aren't the defaults for backward compatibilty.

        cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

        // Sets how errors will appear.
        // During web page *development* TemplateExceptionHandler.HTML_DEBUG_HANDLER is better.
        cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);

        // Don't log exceptions inside FreeMarker that it will thrown at you anyway:
        cfg.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);

        // Wrap unchecked exceptions thrown during template processing into TemplateException-s:
        cfg.setWrapUncheckedExceptions(true);

        // Do not fall back to higher scopes when reading a null loop variable:
        cfg.setFallbackOnNullLoopVariable(false);

        cfg.setTemplateLoader(new FileTemplateLoader(new File("templates")));
        Properties settings = new Properties();
        settings.setProperty("auto_import", "/spring.ftl as spring");
        cfg.setSettings(settings);

        return cfg;
    }
```

Error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: templates does not exist.
    at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader$1.run(FileTemplateLoader.java:123) ~[freemarker-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader$1.run(FileTemplateLoader.java:119) ~[freemarker-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.<init>(FileTemplateLoader.java:119) ~[freemarker-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
    at freemarker.cache.FileTemplateLoader.<init>(FileTemplateLoader.java:98) ~[freemarker-2.3.32.jar:2.3.32]
```

Comment: `src/main/resources` is not a file path but part of the classpath. You cannot use a `FileTemplateLoader`. You need to use the `ClassTemplateLoader` to load from the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the classloader exception using the implementation below :

```
cfg.setTemplateLoader(new ClassTemplateLoader(DocGeneratorUtils.class, "/templates"));
Properties settings = new Properties();
settings.setProperty("auto_import", "/spring.ftl as spring");
cfg.setSettings(settings);
```